# Why is protein cyclisation desirable?

Tags: protein-structure

There are a number of methods to "cyclize" an existing peptide:

- Disulphide bond as described in [Disulfide Bond Mimetics: Strategies and Challenges](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/chem.201703199) by Gori et al.
- "Linchpin" based (linker chemistry) as described in [Synthetic Cross-linking of Peptides: Molecular Linchpins for Peptide Cyclization](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30457043/) by Derda et al.

Why would the "cyclization" of a protein be a desirable goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the abstract of [Synthetic Cross-linking of Peptides: Molecular Linchpins for Peptide Cyclization](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30457043/) by Derda et al., protein cyclization improves:

> resistance to proteolytic degradation and conformational stability. The latter property leads to an increase in binding potency and increased bioavailability due to increased permeation through biological membranes.

In simpler terms, a protein that is cyclized is less likely to:

1. Fold into an unhelpful shape.
2. Be broken up by an enzyme.

Thus, they are more likely to:

1. Act as better binders for a given target
2. Make it across a cell membrane